# Spring Boot Microservices - RestTemplate Null Pointer Exception in JUnit Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, resttemplate

I have a problem running Junit Service in my `spring-boot` microservice. I defined bearer token getting from **/authenticate/login**. It is valid. I can send a request to any service through Postman.

I cannot run the test method after copying bearer token and defining it here as shown below.

Here is the its test method

```
@DisplayName("Get Order - Success Scenario")
    @Test
    void test_When_Order_Success() {

        String bearerToken = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJVc2VyIiwiaXNzIjoiUk9MRV9VU0VSICIsImlhdCI6MTY3MTQ4ODgyMiwiZXhwIjoxNjcxNDg4OTQyfQ.g83kKmFzDH539ZcpxM9D8bE_famFOevkOqNst_E8YG07b4yR4cEqcrySvz36vw8GJxTKm9gUQIM1J_G8cC5RGQ";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

        //Mocking
        Order order = getMockOrder();
        when(orderRepository.findById(anyLong()))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(order));

        when(restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/" + order.getProductId(),
                HttpMethod.GET, request, ProductResponse.class).getBody()).thenReturn(getMockProductResponse());

        when(restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://PAYMENT-SERVICE/payment/order/" + order.getId(),
                HttpMethod.GET, request, PaymentResponse.class).getBody()).thenReturn(getMockPaymentResponse());

        //Actual
        OrderResponse orderResponse = orderService.getOrderDetails(1,bearerToken);

        //Verification
        verify(orderRepository, times(1)).findById(anyLong());
        verify(restTemplate, times(1)).getForObject(
                "http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/" + order.getProductId(),
                ProductResponse.class);
        verify(restTemplate, times(1)).getForObject(
                "http://PAYMENT-SERVICE/payment/order/" + order.getId(),
                PaymentResponse.class);

        //Assert
        assertNotNull(orderResponse);
        assertEquals(order.getId(), orderResponse.getOrderId());
    }
```

Here is the error shown below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity.getBody()" because the return value of "org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(String, org.springframework.http.HttpMethod, org.springframework.http.HttpEntity, java.lang.Class, Object[])" is null
```

How can I fix the issue?

Here is the repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer)

**To run the app,**

1. Run Service Registery (Eureka Server)
2. Run config server
3. Run zipkin and redis through these commands shown below on docker

   docker run -d -p 9411:9411 openzipkin/zipkin
   docker run -d --name redis -p 6379:6379 redis
4. Run api gateway
5. Run other services

Comment: I'm not goinng to wrote about the test and the idea of mocking RestTemplate itself. The thing is, it looks like you're misusing the Mockito.when() function. You try mocking the `getBody()` invocation on object returned by the call of this method `restTemplate.exchange(
                "http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/" + order.getProductId(),
                HttpMethod.GET, request, ProductResponse.class)`.

Comment: @AndrewMcCoist I asked a new question but I still couldn't fix it. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844264/spring-boot-microservices-junit-test-java-lang-nullpointerexception-cannot-inv

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> when(restTemplate.exchange(
>                 "http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/" + order.getProductId(),
>                 HttpMethod.GET, request, ProductResponse.class).getBody()).thenReturn(getMockProductResponse());
>
> when(restTemplate.exchange(
>                 "http://PAYMENT-SERVICE/payment/order/" + order.getId(),
>                 HttpMethod.GET, request, PaymentResponse.class).getBody()).thenReturn(getMockPaymentResponse());
> ```

You would have to first mock `restTemplate.exchange(...)` and return a mocked `ResponseEntity`. Then you can mock `responseEntity.getBody()`.

Please note that RestTemplate is deprecated and should be replaced with WebClient: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

In our project we're using the following best practice:

Wrap the RestTemplate/ WebClient with a Client component, which does not provide any business logic, just a nice API.
We're testing this class with SpringBootTest and Wiremock.
In the services we then can mock this custom client, which is much easier than mocking RestTemplate/ WebClient.

Comment: I asked a new question but I still couldn't fix it. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844264/spring-boot-microservices-junit-test-java-lang-nullpointerexception-cannot-inv

Comment: Did you use a different StackOverflow account? Please don't duplicate you questions. Just edit/ add updates to the original ones.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocking the method, you can mock the response by using **WireMock**. This can make your test more realistic.

Also, calling `RestTemplate` means you are doing an integration test. This also means you are loading all your `spring` context and access your controller through a query you send with your `RestTemplate` and you don't need to mock your repository nor your service. You can only mock an external service while doing an integration or and end to end test.

Comment: I asked a new question but I still couldn't fix it. Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844264/spring-boot-microservices-junit-test-java-lang-nullpointerexception-cannot-inv